# Error en registro de usuarios vuejs, firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

estoy siguiendo un tutorial en este se realizo una zona de registro en la cual los datos se mandan a firebase para una autenticación por email y password,
se supone que cuando la persona ya esta registrada seria redirigido a la pagina inicial o me enviaria a un catch en caso de que ocurriera un error (lo que esta sucediendo)

el error que me aparece es:

> FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first
>   argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined at new
>   FirestoreError (

¿alguna idea de que pueda ser o que deba revisar?
en el firestore en autenticación si aparece el usuario creado pero en el cloud firestore no se crea la coleccion.

el codigo que creo genera el error seria

```
methods: {
      register (user) {
        this.$store.dispatch('firebaseRegister', user)
      .then((userRegistered) => {
        const data = {
          uid: userRegistered.uid,
          email: user.email,
          role: 'customer'
        };
        db.collection('users').doc(userRegistered.uid).set(data).then(() => {
          this.$store.commit('setRole', data.role);
          this.$router.push('/');
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.message = error.message.substr(0, 60);
        this.snackBar = true;
        console.log(error);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.snackBar = false;
        }, this.timeout);
      })
  }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: `userRegistered.uid` es undefined por eso el error, ¿tienes idea de porque es undefined?

Comment: realmente en el momento no lo se, si no es algo de lo que escribi arriba pensaria que es una parte en un archivo llamado auth.js que se encarga de la action firebaseRegister y de las mutations de este, pero la verdad no logro identificar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si llegue tarde, pero haciendo un console.log(userRegistered.uid) vas a encontrar que el "uid" esta dentro de "User" así que debería ser "userRegistered.user.uid"

```js
const data = {
          uid: userRegistered.user.uid,
          email: user.email,
          role: 'customer'
        };db.collection('users').doc(userRegistered.user.uid).set(data).then(() => {
          this.$store.commit('setRole', data.role);
          this.$router.push('/');
        });
      })
```